# Import and merge rails database tables

Tags: postgresql, postgres-fdw

I have 3 separate ruby on rails applications running PostgreSQL databases, all with the same tables (and columns) but different values.

For example :

app 1 TABLE

```
name surname postcode
----------
tom  smith   so211ux
```

app 2 TABLE

```
name  surname postcode
----------
mark  smith   so2ddx
```

app 3 TABLE

```
name   surname   postcode
----------
james  roberts   F2D1ux
```

I am looking to export/dump/download from two of the databases and import into one consolidated database/app.

If someone could point me in the right direction/reading for this type of query I would be most grateful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please use the foreign data wrappers (fdw), where you can access the data from external postgresql servers. Please read more here - https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/postgres-fdw.html

Comment: Thanks for the response. I have done some reading on this and i'm not sure this is the best solution. I will not need regular access to the other apps; just a one time dump and import. Would you still recommend FDW?

Comment: Yes, because it is already an in-built extension, so it shouldn't take much time to accomplish the one-time import. It will be just a matter of single insert query.